# ContentValue is inserting null data into my Table in SQLite - android

Tags: android, sqlite

It inserts a row but without any content. i have used this method in previous applications and they all worked well. please help i'm stuck

```
public boolean Insert(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_BUSINESS_NAME,"TEster"); // i tried putting the value directly
    cv.put(COLUMN_BUSINESS_CATEGORY,business_category);
    cv.put(COLUMN_BUSINESS_DESCRIPTION,business_description);
    cv.put(COLUMN_BUSINESS_PHONE,phone_number);
    cv.put(COLUMN_BUSINESS_EMAIL,email_address);
    cv.put(COLUMN_BUSINESS_URL,website);
    cv.put(COLUMN_BUSINESS_ADDRESS,locationAddress.address);
    cv.put(COLUMN_BUSINESS_F_ADDRESS,locationAddress.fAddress);
    cv.put(COLUMN_BUSINESS_LATITUDE,locationAddress.latLng.latitude);
    cv.put(COLUMN_BUSINESS_LONGITUDE,locationAddress.latLng.longitude);
    db.delete(TABLE_MY_BUSINESS, null, null);
    db.insert(TABLE_MY_BUSINESS, COLUMN_ID, cv);
    return true;
}
```

this is how i fetch from the database

```
public void Fetch(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    final String[] column = {COLUMN_BUSINESS_NAME,COLUMN_BUSINESS_CATEGORY,COLUMN_BUSINESS_DESCRIPTION,
            COLUMN_BUSINESS_PHONE,COLUMN_BUSINESS_EMAIL,COLUMN_BUSINESS_URL,COLUMN_BUSINESS_ADDRESS,
            COLUMN_BUSINESS_F_ADDRESS,COLUMN_BUSINESS_LATITUDE,COLUMN_BUSINESS_LONGITUDE};
    String table = TABLE_MY_BUSINESS;
    String selection = COLUMN_ID + " >= ? ";
    String[] selectionArgs = {"0"};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(table,column,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        this.business_name = cursor.getString(0);
        this.business_category = cursor.getString(1);
        this.business_description = cursor.getString(2);
        this.phone_number = cursor.getString(3);
        this.email_address = cursor.getString(4);
        this.website = cursor.getString(5);
        this.locationAddress.setAddress(cursor.getString(6));
        this.locationAddress.setfAddress(cursor.getString(7));
        this.locationAddress.setLatLng(cursor.getInt(8),cursor.getInt(9));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}
```

this is how i created the table

```
String CREATE_MY_BUSINESS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_MY_BUSINESS+" " + "("
            +COLUMN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            +COLUMN_BUSINESS_NAME+" TEXT,"
            +COLUMN_BUSINESS_CATEGORY+" TEXT,"
            +COLUMN_BUSINESS_DESCRIPTION+" TEXT,"
            +COLUMN_BUSINESS_PHONE+" TEXT,"
            +COLUMN_BUSINESS_EMAIL+" TEXT,"
            +COLUMN_BUSINESS_URL+" TEXT,"
            +COLUMN_BUSINESS_ADDRESS+" TEXT,"
            +COLUMN_BUSINESS_F_ADDRESS+" TEXT,"
            +COLUMN_BUSINESS_LONGITUDE+" INTEGER,"
            +COLUMN_BUSINESS_LATITUDE+" INTEGER)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
```

Comment: Replace `insert()` with `insertOrThrow()`.

Comment: still not working

Comment: Are you sure that this function actually gets called?

Comment: yes im sure. it gets called and inserts a new row into the database. but the values of the row are null. ive used the same code in other apps and it worked so im really lost here

Comment: This code looks OK (except for the ignored value of `insert`). If the name column does not contain "TEster", then this code does not get executed, or some other codes changes the data.

Comment: ive added more information.

Comment: the name column does not contain Tester infact thats why i put it there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
while (cursor.isAfterLast()) {
```

The body of this `while` loop is executed only if the cursor is empty.

Executing a query positions a cursor before the first entry, so the easiest way to iterate through a cursor is like this:

```java
Cursor cursor = db.query(...);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thx soooooooooooo much. ur a life saver